# Removing a specific value in a nested list of values from a dictionary

Tags: python

Currently, I have the dictionary:

```
d = {'m1': [None, ['w3', 'w2', 'w1']], 'm2': [None, ['w3', 'w1', 'w2']], 'm3': [None, ['w2', 'w1', 'w3']]}
```

Formatted, it looks like this (for easier reading):

```
m1 -> [None, ['w3', 'w2', 'w1']]
m2 -> [None, ['w3', 'w1', 'w2']]
m3 -> [None, ['w2', 'w1', 'w3']]
```

And

```
to_match = 'm2'
```

**to_match** is a string and and if it matches a key in dictionary **d**, it will replace None with the first item in that list, and then delete itself from the list. I am very confused how to proceed with this.

**For example...**

So, because **to_match** is **'m2'** it would look for the key m2, replace None with the first item in the list, and remove itself from the list. Looking like this:

Before:

```
'm2': [None, ['w3', 'w1', 'w2']]
```

what 'm2' should look like after:

```
'm2': ['w3', ['w1', 'w2']]
```

And the entire dictionary:

```
d = {'m1': [None, ['w3', 'w2', 'w1']], 'm2': ['w3', ['w1', 'w2']], 'm3': [None, ['w2', 'w1', 'w3']]}
```

How can I change the entire dictionary to look like this?

**Current Code:**

```
d = {'m1': [None, ['w3', 'w2', 'w1']], 'm2': [None, ['w3', 'w1', 'w2']], 'm3': [None, ['w2', 'w1', 'w3']]}

to_match = 'm2'

def replace(d: dictionary, to_match):
   for key, value in d.items():
       if to_match in key:



   return 



replace(d, to_match)
```

Comment: Is there a significance to the fact that you're storing a value as a list with two elements, where the second element is itself a list? That makes your data structure quite a bit harder to work with...

Comment: You also don't need to iterate over the items in the dictionary to find `'m2'`…you can simply do `d.get('m2')`, and if it is non-`None`, do the necessary replacement.

Comment: What precisely to you mean when you say `to_match` should "match" a key? Equality?

Comment: @Hamms Yes so if 'm2' == 'm2'.

Comment: @dtanabe Oh I did not know that, thank you. As for the signifiance, unfortunately that is just the structure of the dictionary I have to deal with...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This following piece of code will help you out.
You do not need to run for loop on the keys as python dictionaries are like hashtables the key is hashed to match to a value.

```
def replace(d, to_match):
    if to_match in d:
        d[to_match][0] = d[to_match][1].pop(0)
    return
```

I don't know your other requirements but this should do what you need

Comment: Very clean solution. Assumes no deviation in the data structure, but very well suited for what's there.

Answer (score 1):

Not terribly resilient against errors, but:

```
d = {'m1': [None, ['w3', 'w2', 'w1']], 'm2': [None, ['w3', 'w1', 'w2']], 'm3': [None, ['w2', 'w1', 'w3']]}

to_match = 'm2'

def replace(d, to_match):
    value_list = d.get(to_match)
    if value_list is not None:
        # assuming your values are always lists of 2
        head, remainder = value_list
        if remainder:
            new_value_list = [remainder[0], remainder[1:]]
        else:
            # just guessing? really depends on what your requirements are...
            new_value_list = [None, []]
        d[to_match] = new_value_list
        return head


replace(d, to_match)
print(d)
```